# Set Rplots.pdf generation location

Tags: r, bash

I am currently writing a bash file `run.sh` that runs some python code, followed by some code in an `.R` file. I call the file, `data_analysis.r`, using `Rscript data_analysis.r` inside `run.sh`.

Each time I run the script, it generates an `Rplots.pdf` file, which I am okay with, but I would like to set the file to generate at a custom location.

For now, I can simply add a line in `run.sh` that renames and moves the `Rplots.pdf` file to the intended location, but I'm not quite happy with this solution.

Does anyone know how to set a custom location for the `Rplots.pdf` file generated by `Rscript`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a line in data_analysis.r which says

```
pdf(file="RPlots.pdf")
```

You can edit this line to location you want and hard code it.

```
pdf(file="/mylocation/RPlots.pdf")
```

Comment: There wasn't one at first, but I added it and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Note that this call needs to precede any other call, otherwise it will overwrite the file with an empty PDF.